# Can we always recover a matrix from its eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If we're given all the eigenvalues of a square matrix $A$ and the corresponding eigenvectors of each eigenvalue, then in what case(s) is it possible theoretically to recover $A$ from this much information? And how exactly when it is possible?

Comment: In general you can't. This is not nearly enough information, unless there are so many eigenvectors that they span the whole space (in which case, of course, you can).

Answer (score 5):

In general, this will be possible only if the matrix is diagonalizable. In that case, we simply form the matrix $P$ of eigenvectors and the diagonal matrix $D$ ordered corresponding to $P$. Then
$$A = PDP^{-1}$$
You essentially need a basis and you need to know how the matrix acts on the basis to determine the mapping. The eigenvectors and the eigenvalues for a diagonalizable matrix gives you precisely the needed amount of information, but for non-diagonalizable matrices there will be non-trivial Jordan blocks of the matrix which are not recoverable (even if you are given the generalized eigenvectors).